# Compute difference of numbers of 2 arrays

Tags: c#, linq

for each number in A and each number in B if their difference is more than 3 ,add the new number

```
A={6,7,10}
B={2,3}
result={4,5,4,8,7}
```

for example :

6-2=4 true Add 4

6-3=3 false

7-2=5 true Add 5

my attempt :

```
  var result = A.Select((a, i) => new
  {
   desired = a - B[i] > 3 ? a - B[i] :0

   });
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var query = from a in A
            from b in B
            let diff = a - b
            where diff > 3
            select diff;
```

Or in dot notation, which drops out really neatly:

```
var query = A.SelectMany(a => B, (a, b) => a - b)
             .Where(x => x > 3);
```

With your test data:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()        
    {
        int[] A = {6, 7, 10};
        int[] B = {2, 3};

        var query = A.SelectMany(a => B, (a, b) => a - b)
                     .Where(x => x > 3);

        foreach (var result in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var query = from a in A
            from b in B
            where (a - b) > 3
            select a - b;
```